# Use local Icon svg in project

Tags: css, svg, vue.js

I'm trying to render an SVG on the screen using css. Here is my file structure. `Root > Assets > Icon > user-icon.svg`. So, I'm trying to add that using CSS like this:

```
.user-element {
  background-image: url(/assets/icons/user-icon.svg);
}
```

But nothing is showing up on the screen and I'm getting this error in the console:

`GET http://localhost:4000/assets/icons/user-icon.svg 404 (Not Found)`

I'm not trying to make a network request. More just trying to find the SVG in my local file system. Any help on this would be great Thank You!

Comment: is it `Icon` or `icons` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in front of url put this: `./` and put the path in quotes (`''`) like below:

```
.user-element {
  background-image: url('./assets/icons/user-icon.svg');
}
```

If again it does not work then it means that the path is wrong

But as i can see in your question,you say that the icon is in `assets/icon/user-icon.svg` but in css code you are using `assets/icons/user-icon.svg` so the path it is wrong.Try to use the below code:

```
.user-element {
  background-image: url(./assets/icon/user-icon.svg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of URL, just a path, the browser will prepend the scheme, server and port of the current page.
To access local filesystem try the [`file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) scheme.